# Laravel middlware for testing

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit, token

I've build an api in Laravel 5.3 with jwt web tokens. If I want to test this I've to add this before every request:

```
if ((\App::environment() == 'testing') && array_key_exists("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION", Request::server())) {
    JWTAuth::setRequest(\Route::getCurrentRequest());
}
```

If I add this to the constructor in my controller it's working. But when I add this to a middleware all my tests are failing.

I've added the middleware to the `$routeMiddleware` array in `kernel.php`. The middleware looks like this:

```
class TestingKeepRequest
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ((\App::environment() == 'testing') && array_key_exists("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION", Request::server())) {
            JWTAuth::setRequest(\Route::getCurrentRequest());
            dd('test');
        }

        $next($request);
    }
}
```

When I `dd('test');` in the `if statement` the `dd('test');` is being is being reached.

The middleware is being assigned in my routes file like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['testing', 'active', 'throttle']], function () { //etc....
```

So why is this working in the constructor of a controller but not in a middleware?

Comment: Not sure if I'm correct, but did you forgot to return the callback? Try `return $next($request)` to chain the request/response flow

Comment: Wauw indeed thanks! looking for hours -_-

Comment: You're welcome :) Middlewares are nothing but just organized pieces of logic that sits between request and response, and you need to chain them by returning the result. Any exceptions happens in between or no returns, will result in a halt in the response. So, have fun!